# comparing constant with variable php

Tags: php

I have the following PHP-code:

```
<?php

    define('TEMPLATE_DIR','basic');

    $info = file_get_contents('info.txt');

    preg_match('/template_dir=(.*)/',$info,$dir); // $dir[1] gives 'basic'

    if(TEMPLATE_DIR == $dir[1]){

        echo 'true';

    }else{

        echo 'false';

    };

?>
```

info.txt contains this:

```
template_name=basic
template_dir=basic
```

This gives a 'false'. What's the problem?

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` of bothh and share it with us.

Comment: This works perfectly fine, and gives o/p as `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `'false'` means that the strings are different. You can verify that yourself with a debugger or with [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).

Your regular expression captures everything after the `=` sign, including leading and trailing spaces and line feeds. I don't think that's what you want.

Try being more flexible:

```
if (TEMPLATE_DIR == trim($dir[1]) ){
}
```